# Como encontrar el punto mas cercano en un Array de Coordenadas

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Javascript para encontrar la coordenada mas cercana.

Tengo un array de 20 coordenadas y otro punto P1

```
var array = [{lat:xxx, lng:xxx},
             {lat:xxx, lng:xxx},
             {lat:xxx, lng:xxx},
              ...
            ]
```

`P1 = {lat:xxx, lng:xxx}`

He logrado mediante un Foreach encontrar la distancia entre cada elemento del Array y el P1, de esa manera obtener la distancia mas cercana.

Mi problema surge cuando el array crece, la aplicación tendrá en algún momento cientos de elemento en ese array y es ridículo iterar con TODOS, sería muy tardado. Espero me puedan ayudar con alguna idea. 
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: No veo por que pueda ser ridículo, la velocidad de procesamiento de JS... esa si es ridícula. Ahora, por que no intentas hacerlo con ´array.filter()´

Comment: Lo que sería ridiculo amigo es que no contraigas un limite, es decir, si me dices que tu limite es 100, javascript no tiene problemas con 100 elementos, de hecho es una burla para el, sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que para hacer procesos con imágenes existen formatos como el ArrayBuffer el cuál almacena cientos, o miles de elementos, y pues... en una imagen de 3mb habrán mas de 3 millones de espacios, pero no veo que javascript se trabe al leer y poner esos 3 millones de espacios almacenados en una variable, y ademas tener en cuenta también que el archivo debe ser leído.

Comment: Tambien existe el formato que usa canvas para obtener, guardar y escribir información acerca de imagenes en formato RGB, usando las funciones getImageData y putImageData, que en cuyo caso sería mas o menos lo mismo... lo que te recomiendo es que le pongas un limite al array simplemente, es decir, que compruebes que no se pase del limite definido por ti el array, por ejemplo cargar solo 100 ubicaciones (me parece que sería mejor cargar primero 10), y luego si requieres mas ubicaciones, irlas cargando poco a poco, pero esto siempre controlandolo.

Comment: Luego el proceso sería mas eficiente ya que al obtener las 10 ultimas ubicaciones por separado, hacer que antes de añadirlas al arreglo que las contiene todas, calcules de estas ultimas 10 ubicaciones cual es la mas cercana y luego compararla con la ubicación mas cercana que seguro tendras guardada en otra variable y en caso de que en la nueva lista haya un lugar mas cercano (que no debería haber por logica), reemplazar tu valor actual mas cercano por ese, y por ultimo añadir estas 10 ultimas ubicaciones obtenidas al arreglo que contiene a todas.

Comment: Hola! Tal vez no es muy tarde para preguntar, pero me gustaría saber ¿Cómo hizo para encontrar la coordenada más cercana al P1? Es que yo me encuentro en un caso parecido al suyo, tengo un arreglo con un grupo de coordenada, y a su vez un P1 y quiero comparar entre el array de coordenadas con el P1 para hallar la más cercana solo que no se como realizar la funcion ¿podrías ayudarme? SI con documentación, un ejemplo o como guste te lo agradecería

Answer (score 1):

No se que quieres hacer pero no deberias preocuparte por la velocidad de procesamiento.
Aqui tienes un ejemplo de un bucle de 1.000.000 de elementos, mira la velocidad.

```js
console.time();
var list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i){
  list.push({lat: Math.random()*100, lng: Math.random()*100});
  }
  var point = {lat: Math.random()*100, lng: Math.random()*100};
  var best;
  var best_dif = 9999;
  var dif;
  for(i = 1; i < list.length; ++i){
    dif = Math.abs(point.lat - list[i].lat) +
            Math.abs(point.lng - list[i].lng);
    if(best_dif > dif){
        best_dif = dif;
        best = list[i];
     }
  }
  console.log(point);
  console.log(best, best_dif);
  console.timeEnd();
```